# What is advertising ID in android? how is it related to admob and google play services lib?

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/id.html

Can anyone give detailed answer regarding this question?

Comment: Please include the question here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an opaque identifier for a user that Admob uses to generate a user profile so that they receive more relevant ads. It also allows the user to reset their profile at any time.

What extra do you want that is not clearly provided on that page?

Comment: 'opt out of interest-based ads', what is the use of this option? can you explain in details?

Comment: It means the user can choose to not allow Google to accumulate data about what interests a user has. So Google will not provide them with ads that are tuned to those interests. Ie they will receive random ads instead.